# Conditions on related table in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have issues writing this code correctly. I have `companies`, `categories`, `companies_tags` and `tags` tables. The relations are as follow (baked automatically) :

```php
// CompaniesTable.php
$this->belongsToMany('Tags', [
            'foreignKey' => 'company_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'tag_id',
            'joinTable' => 'companies_tags'
        ]);

$this->belongsTo('Categories', [
            'foreignKey' => 'categorie_id'
        ]);

// CategoriesTable.php
$this->hasMany('Etablissements', [
            'foreignKey' => 'categorie_id'
        ]);

// TagsTable.php
$this->belongsToMany('Companies', [
            'foreignKey' => 'tag_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'company_id',
            'joinTable' => 'companies_tags'
        ]);

// CompaniesTags.php
$this->belongsTo('Companies', [
            'foreignKey' => 'company_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('Tags', [
            'foreignKey' => 'tag_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
```

I have to select companies which name, category name, or one of its tag name contains a specific text.

```php
$ets = (new TableRegistry())
                ->get('Companies')
                ->find('published')
                ->distinct()
                ->contain([
                    "Tags",
                    "Categories"
                    ])
                ->leftJoinWith('Tags', function (\Cake\ORM\Query $q) use ($quoi) {
                    return $q->where(['OR'  => ['Tags.nom LIKE ' => '%' . $quoi . '%', 'Tags.description LIKE' => '%' . $quoi . '%']]);
                })
                ->where(['OR' => ["Companies.nom LIKE" => "%" . $quoi . "%",
                    "Companies.description LIKE" => "%" . $quoi . "%",
                    "Categories.description LIKE" => "%" . $quoi . "%",
                    "Categories.nom LIKE" => "%" . $quoi . "%",
                    ]
                    ]);
```

This query is what I can imagine, but it seems like my LEFT JOIN on `tags` is not working. Can someone help me fix this ?

Comment: Looks like the condition you're putting on the left join should be in the `where` instead? Surely you want to join on the keys defined in the association, and only filter based on the name and description?

Comment: Thanks @Greg Smidt, I want to select Companies with Categories or Tags matching the text the user searched. Companies has a "belongTo" relation with Categories, and a "manyToMany" relation with Tags.

Comment: Understood. But you need to *join* on the keys, not the name or description. Then filter on those using `where`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like that.

```
->contain(["Tags" => function (Query $query, $quoi) {
return $query->select(['field_1', 'field_2'])
    ->where(['OR'  => ['Tags.nom LIKE ' => '%' . $quoi . '%', 'Tags.description LIKE' => '%' . $quoi . '%']]); }, "Categories" ])
```

Comment: This does not solve my issue. Perhaps, I need to use some tactics to have it solved. Thank you.